# Android: Google Maps API v1 to v2

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I've got android app (source) which is using google maps api v1. Unfortunately I can't use it because I can't generate maps key for v1 api. And because of that maps are not showing.

Is there an easy way for changing source code to be compatible with v2 google maps api? I've tried this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html but without bigger success (I'm newbie in android development)

```
public class MapviewGeolocation extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mc;
    public static float currentLatitude = Resources.lat;
    public static float currentLongitude = Resources.lon;
    // private MyLocationOverlay myLocation;
    private List<Event> items;

    SharedPreferences sp;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // STRICTMODE
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        sp = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        items = new ArrayList<Event>();

        final Location myCurrentLocation = this.getLastBestLocation();

        if (myCurrentLocation != null) {
            if (Resources.isByGps) {
                currentLatitude = (float) myCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
                currentLongitude = (float) myCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
            }

        } else {

            currentLatitude = Resources.lat;
            currentLongitude = Resources.lon;

        }

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mc = mapView.getController();
        mc.setZoom(13);
        GeoPoint geo = new GeoPoint((int) (currentLatitude * 1e6),
                (int) (currentLongitude * 1e6));
        mc.animateTo(geo);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        MyLocationOverlay mylocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this,
                mapView);
        mylocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        mapView.getOverlays().add(mylocationOverlay);

        InitMapTask init_map_task = new InitMapTask();
        init_map_task.execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        String adres = sp.getString("adres", "");

        if (adres.length() < 1) {
            Resources.isByGps = true;
        } else {
            Resources.isByGps = false;
        }

        if (!Resources.isByGps) {

            currentLatitude = sp.getFloat("lat", Resources.lat);
            currentLongitude = sp.getFloat("lon", Resources.lon);
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 200, this);
        }

        mapView.refreshDrawableState();
        mapView.invalidate();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        if (Resources.isByGps) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }

    private void addOverlays() {

        items = Resources.events;

    }

    public Drawable getDrawable(int population) {

        Drawable drawable = null;

        if (population < 300)
            drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pins_rose);
        else if ((300 <= population) && (500 > population))
            drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pins_bleu);
        else if ((500 <= population) && (800 > population))
            drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pins_vert);
        else if ((800 <= population) && (1000 > population))
            drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pins_jaune);
        else
            drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pins_blanc);

        return drawable;
    }

    private void addOverlay(MapItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay) {
        Event ev = itemizedOverlay.getLocation();
        GeoPoint location = new GeoPoint((int) (ev.getLat() * 1E6),
                (int) (ev.getLon() * 1E6));
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(location, ev.getTitle(),
                ev.getCity());
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (Resources.isTesting) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getBaseContext(),
                    "Localization changed - current: Latitude = "
                            + currentLatitude + " Longitude = "
                            + currentLongitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // if (Resources.isByGps) {
        if (location != null) {
            currentLatitude = (float) location.getLatitude();
            currentLongitude = (float) location.getLongitude();
            GeoPoint geo = new GeoPoint((int) (currentLatitude * 1e6),
                    (int) (currentLongitude * 1e6));
            mc.animateTo(geo);
        }
        // }

        mapView.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        if (Resources.isTesting)
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is off...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        if (Resources.isTesting)
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is on...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        if (Resources.isTesting)
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS status changed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
    }

    public class InitMapTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog progress;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progress = new ProgressDialog(MapviewGeolocation.this);
            progress.setMessage("Loading...");
            progress.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            addOverlays();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                int color = 0;
                Drawable drawable = getDrawable(400);

                MapItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(
                        drawable, mapView, MapviewGeolocation.this, color,
                        items.get(i), currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

                addOverlay(itemizedOverlay);
            }

            mapView.invalidate();
            progress.dismiss();

        }

    }

    /**
     * @return the last know best location
     */
    private Location getLastBestLocation() {
        LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location locationGPS = mLocationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Location locationNet = mLocationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        long GPSLocationTime = 0;
        if (null != locationGPS) {
            GPSLocationTime = locationGPS.getTime();
        }

        long NetLocationTime = 0;

        if (null != locationNet) {
            NetLocationTime = locationNet.getTime();
        }

        if (0 < GPSLocationTime - NetLocationTime) {
            return locationGPS;
        } else {
            return locationNet;
        }

    }

    // action for bottom menu
    public void actionLista(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ListviewActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void actionMapa(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MapviewGeolocation.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void actionSettings(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: why don't you follow the docs @ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start